# What is the default access modifier in Java?

Tags: java, access-modifiers

What is the default access modifier for a method or an instance variable if I do not state it explicitly?

For example:

```
package flight.booking;

public class FlightLog
{
    private SpecificFlight flight;

    FlightLog(SpecificFlight flight)
    {
        this.flight = flight;
    }
}
```

Is the access modifier of this constructor protected or package? Can other classes in the same package, which is `flight.booking`, call this constructor?

Comment: It is already covered in [this old question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/215497/in-java-whats-the-difference-between-public-default-protected-and-private?rq=1) look for "no modifier" and "default"

Comment: I googled for "java default access modifier" and the first result was [Controlling Access to Members of a Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html) from Oracle. A simple search...

Comment: thank you, i searched but i could not find the same question. No need fordownvote

Comment: SO is far more straightforward for specific questions than official documentation, so I'll click a prominent SO search result before trying a page from a manual. I appreciate strictly unnecessary questions like this.

Comment: Yes. Other classes can use the constructor. See this [cheat sheet](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33627846/276052).

Comment: Update **Java 8** usage of `default` keyword:
As many others have noted The default visibility (no keyword)

> the field will be accessible from inside the same package to which the
> class belongs.

Not to be confused with the new **Java 8** feature ([Default Methods][1]) that allows an interface to provide an implementation when its labeled with the `default` keyword.

See: [Access modifiers][2]


  [1]: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html
  [2]: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html

Answer (score 137, accepted):

From Java [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html)

> If a class has no modifier (the default, also known as package-private), it is visible only within its own package (packages are named groups of related classes — you will learn about them in a later lesson.)

At the `member level`, you can also use the public modifier or `no modifier` (package-private) just as with top-level classes, and with the same meaning.

Full story you can read here (<sub>Which I wrote recently</sub>):

*http://codeinventions.blogspot.com/2014/09/default-access-modifier-in-java-or-no.html*

Comment: he's asking about the entire class, not the contents of the class.

Answer (score 134):

From documentation:

```
Access Levels
Modifier        Class    Package    Subclass    World
-----------------------------------------------------
public           Y        Y          Y           Y
protected        Y        Y          Y           N
(Default)        Y        Y          N           N
private          Y        N          N           N
```

Comment: Default seems slightly out of place since a subclass could reference something with the "default modifier" (no) provided the inheritance occurs within the same package.

Comment: what does world significate?

Comment: @EvinUgur I think it makes sense, you can have, for example, a class _Canine_, which has a default method _eatHumans()_, Wolves extend from that, but then you have a package _pets_ somewhere, which contains the class _Dog_ that also extends from Canine, but you don't want it to eatHumans.

Comment: @ziMtyth World, as in "Global", accessible from anywhere we have an instance of that class.

Comment: In case anybody else wants it, [here's the doc that explains it](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html)

Comment: What's the point of the Subclass column? Is it meant to say "Subclass in other Package" (since Subclass in Package is already contained by Package)?

Answer (score 46):

It depends on the context.

When it's within a class:

```
class example1 {

    int a = 10; // This is package-private (visible within package)

    void method1() // This is package-private as well.
    {
        -----
    }
}
```

When it's within a interface:

```
interface example2 {

    int b = 10; // This is public and static.
    void method2(); // This is public and abstract
}
```

Comment: Member variables in interface are also `final`.

Answer (score 22):

Default access modifier is package-private - visible only from the same package

Comment: why you write visible from the same package, you means if we write class A { int a=0; }, so it should be accessible from other class with the package ??

Answer (score 15):

Here is a code sample which should pretty much sum this up for you... In addition to the below, showing how you can't access a default in another package there is one more thing.

Default is not accessible in a subclass if the class that subclasses it is in another package, but it is accessible if the subclass is in the same package.

```
package main;

public class ClassA {
    private int privateVar;
    public int publicVar;
    int defaultVar;
}

package main;

public class ClassB {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ClassA a = new ClassA();
        int v1 = a.publicVar;   // Works
        int v2 = a.defaultVar;  // Works
        int v3 = a.privateVar;  // Doesn't work

    }
}

package other;

public class ClassC {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ClassA a = new ClassA();
        int v1 = a.publicVar;   // Works
        int v2 = a.defaultVar;  // Doesn't work
        int v3 = a.privateVar;  // Doesn't work
    }
}
```

Comment: I gave you +1 but then I noticed one mistake in your explanation. It says "Default is non accessible in sub-classes and acts like a private (and doesn't act like a protected or public when it comes to a subclass)." which not true.
In case of subclass, if it is in same package it can access members with default access modifier while if it is in another package then it can't. So please correct it!!!

Remember: 'default' access modifier is package-private which means every class (whether extending it or not) within same package can access it.

Comment: Excellent find. I modified the wording.

Comment: Thx, this example

Answer (score 5):

The default modifier is `package`. Only code in the same package will be able to invoke this constructor.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it is visible in the same package. Anything outside that package will not be allowed to access it.

Answer (score 3):

The Default access modifier is **package-private** (i.e DEFAULT) and it is visible **only** from the same package.

Answer (score 2):

Your constructor's access modifier would be **package-private(default)**. As you have declared the class public, it will be visible everywhere, but the constructor will not. Your constructor will be visible only in its package.

```
package flight.booking;

public class FlightLog // Public access modifier
{
    private SpecificFlight flight;

    FlightLog(SpecificFlight flight) // Default access modifier
    {
        this.flight = flight;
    }
}
```

When you do not write any constructor in your class then the compiler generates a default constructor with the same access modifier of the class. For the following example, the compiler will generate a default constructor with the **public** access modifier (same as class).

```
package flight.booking;

public class FlightLog // Public access modifier
{
    private SpecificFlight flight;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't call the default access level to the other package. But you have the access within the package. Follow [this link](http://vhariprasath.blogspot.in/2014/04/modifiers-in-java.html) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Default access modifier - If a class has no modifier (the default, also known as package-private), it is visible only within its own package (packages are named groups of related classes).

Answer (score 0):

> Is the access modifier of this constructor protected or package?

I think implicitly your constructors access modifier would be your class's access modifier. as your class has public access, constructor would have public access implicitly

Comment: No, it's package-private: only classes in the same package can instantiate it.

Answer (score 0):

From a book named *OCA Java SE 7 Programmer I*:

> The members of a class defined without using any explicit access
>   modifier are defined with package accessibility (also called default
>   accessibility). The members with package access are only accessible to
>   classes and interfaces defined in the same package.