# What's the default access modifier for local class members?

Tags: java

Meaning if I ommit the access modifier for members of local classes, can the class declaring method access the members? And who else exactly?

I'm talking about local classes, that are classes **defined inside a method**

**THEREFORE THIS IS NOT A DUPLICATE**

Comment: have a look at http://www.javatpoint.com/access-modifiers

Comment: possible duplicate of [In Java, what's the difference between public, default, protected, and private?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/215497/in-java-whats-the-difference-between-public-default-protected-and-private)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the default access modifier in java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16164902/what-is-the-default-access-modifier-in-java)

Answer (score 2):

Local classes cannot be declared public, protected, private, or static. These modifiers are for members of classes; they are not allowed with local variable declarations or local class declarations.

```
*Meaning if I ommit the access modifier for members of local classes, can the class declaring method access the members?*
```

No the class declaring the method cannot access the local class members. [A local class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/localclasses.html) is visible only within the block that defines it; it can never be used outside that block.

Comment: I'm not talking about the class declaring **the** method, but the class-declaring-method, the method that declares the inner local class.

Answer (score 1):

The default modifier is package level  modifier. Accessable inside the package.

Comment: Your are mixing [inner classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/innerclasses.html) with [local classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/localclasses.html).