# What does no flags for field means in Class format in JAVA?

Tags: java, javap

Here is my snippet of code :

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        class EnglishHelloThere {
              int a=10;
        }
    }

}
```

I created a local class to see what kind of access modifier do i get when not written any modifier for variable in local class from compiler.

This is what i got in JAVAP

```
  Compiled from "Test.java"
class com.Test$1EnglishHelloThere
  SourceFile: "Test.java"
  EnclosingMethod: #21.#23                // com.Test.main
  InnerClasses:
       #27= #1; //EnglishHelloThere=class com/Test$1EnglishHelloThere
  minor version: 0
  major version: 51
  flags: ACC_SUPER
Constant pool:
   #1 = Class              #2             //  com/Test$1EnglishHelloThere
   #2 = Utf8               com/Test$1EnglishHelloThere
   #3 = Class              #4             //  java/lang/Object
   #4 = Utf8               java/lang/Object
   #5 = Utf8               a
   #6 = Utf8               I
   #7 = Utf8               <init>
   #8 = Utf8               ()V
   #9 = Utf8               Code
  #10 = Methodref          #3.#11         //  java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
  #11 = NameAndType        #7:#8          //  "<init>":()V
  #12 = Fieldref           #1.#13         //  com/Test$1EnglishHelloThere.a:I
  #13 = NameAndType        #5:#6          //  a:I
  #14 = Utf8               LineNumberTable
  #15 = Utf8               LocalVariableTable
  #16 = Utf8               this
  #17 = Utf8               Lcom/Test$1EnglishHelloThere;
  #18 = Utf8               SourceFile
  #19 = Utf8               Test.java
  #20 = Utf8               EnclosingMethod
  #21 = Class              #22            //  com/Test
  #22 = Utf8               com/Test
  #23 = NameAndType        #24:#25        //  main:([Ljava/lang/String;)V
  #24 = Utf8               main
  #25 = Utf8               ([Ljava/lang/String;)V
  #26 = Utf8               InnerClasses
  #27 = Utf8               EnglishHelloThere
{
  int a;
    flags:

  com.Test$1EnglishHelloThere();
    flags:
    Code:
      stack=2, locals=1, args_size=1
         0: aload_0
         1: invokespecial #10                 // Method java/lang/Object."<init>
":()V
         4: aload_0
         5: bipush        10
         7: putfield      #12                 // Field a:I
        10: return
      LineNumberTable:
        line 12: 0
        line 13: 4
        line 12: 10
      LocalVariableTable:
        Start  Length  Slot  Name   Signature
               0      11     0  this   Lcom/Test$1EnglishHelloThere;
}
```

So basically flags field is left blank so i'm confused what kind of access modifier does this variable get

because if i add 
`private int a=10;` or `public int a=10;` i get

```
public int a;
  flags: ACC_PUBLIC
```

or

```
protected int a;
  flags: ACC_PROTECTED
```

So what kind of access modifier does a gets by default ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the default access modifier in java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16164902/what-is-the-default-access-modifier-in-java)

Comment: It gets no access modifiers by default, note you can't add `private` or `protected` to a local variable.  You can only make it `final`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following table shows the access to members permitted by each modifier.

[image]

But this access modifier can be confusing "Note the term Permitted here".It's worth noting that
 Local inner classes are local to code blocks
From this i mean to say that 
Local inner classes also called method local inner classes are not members of the class of which the code is a part but are local to the code block they belong to, just as a local variable.

It can't be accessed outside the block in which they are defined.

For Example Suppose i read write this code in one package

```
package packageone.com;
public class HavingLocalClass {
    public HavingLocalClass() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
     void TestMethod(int a){
        class LocalClass{
            int localVar;
            public void display(){
            System.out.println(localVar);
            }

            public LocalClass(int localVar) {
                this.localVar=localVar;
                // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            }



            }

            LocalClass lc=new LocalClass(a);
            System.out.println(lc.localVar);
            /* If i directly try to print localVar here it will
                give me error */
            //System.out.println(localVar);//cannot be resolved into variable


    }
}
```

now in the same package if i try to print i have to access it through that method only.

```
package packageone.com;

public class TestingMain {
public static void main(String...strings){
HavingLocalClass tsp= new HavingLocalClass();
tsp.TestMethod(85);
}
}
```

output `85`

Answer (score 1):

The default - when no modifier is present - is package private (aka package local). Which restricts the visibility to within the same package. That is irrespective of where the class is defined (top-level, inner, anonymous or method local).

That said, the visibility of fields of method local classes is not very relevant, as they are limited to the scope of the method.

Comment: @PeterLawrey The question is about a field in a method-local class. That said, the visibility of fields of method local classes is not very relevant, as they are limited to the scope of the method.

Answer (score 0):

It will get default/package-private modifier if not specified with any other modifier.Also a local variable can't be assigned with any other modifier(protected,public or private) but default.Also it can be added with final to restrict its value change.For more [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215497/in-java-whats-the-difference-between-public-default-protected-and-private?rq=1)